Request to firebase function that expects parameters from flutter app received without parameters
here i'm calling cloud function
final result =
          await FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('example').call(
        {
          'test1': 'test1',
          'test2': 'test2,
        },
      );

in the CF I printed every possible field

@functions_framework.http
def generate_post(request) -> https_fn.Response:
        # Print headers
    print("Headers:")
    for header, value in request.headers.items():
        print(f"{header}: {value}")

    # Print query parameters
    print("\nQuery Parameters:")
    for param, value in request.args.items():
        print(f"{param}: {value}")

    # Print form data
    print("\nForm Data:")
    for field, value in request.form.items():
        print(f"{field}: {value}")

    # Print JSON data
    data = request.get_json(silent=True)
    print("\nJSON Data:")
    print(data)

    # Print raw data
    print("\nRaw Data:")
    print(request.data.decode('utf-8'))
    logging.info(f"Request data: {request.data}")

**all of them are empty **
I called it using postman, it managed to read the parameters
here're the dependencies I use
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  firebase_core: ^3.1.1
  firebase_auth: ^5.1.1
  cloud_firestore: ^5.0.2
  flutter_redux: ^0.10.0
  redux: ^5.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.3
  cloud_functions: ^5.0.3
  http: ^1.2.2


 flutter --version
Flutter 3.19.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ba39319843 (5 months ago) • 2024-03-07 15:22:21 -0600
Engine • revision 2e4ba9c6fb
Tools • Dart 3.3.1 • DevTools 2.31.1

any idea ?
Thanks in advance
I can't find other way to call firebase CF other than what I did

Your client code is using the provided Firebase SDK for callable functions, but your function itself is not a callable function at all - it's an HTTP function.  They are not compatible with each other.  Callable functions have a special protocol that needs to be observed on both the client and backend.
If you want to use a callable function, both your client and function code need to match, as described in the documentation.  That means your python function needs to be annotated with @https_fn.on_call() instead of @functions_framework.http, and it needs to be deployed with the Firebase CLI.
If you don't want to use Firebase callable functions, then ignore all of the documentation about callables and just use HTTP type functions with a normal HTTP request from the client.
